# Definition of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

One definition of a maximal ideal is as follows:

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is maximal if $I\neq R$ and the only ideals which contain $I$ are $I$ and $R$.

An equivalent definition is

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is maximal if $I\neq R$ and $R/I$ is simple.

Why is the second definition equivalent to the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the first definition, and let $I$ be maximal. Then note that $R/I$ is simple because if it had a non-trivial ideal $J$ this would correspond to an ideal properly containing $I$ and not equal to $R$. You can read about that correspondance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69578/bijection-between-ideals-of-r-i-and-ideals-containing-i)

The other direction is the same. If you assume the second definition, and let $I$ be an ideal such that $R/I$ is simple, then the only ideals in $R/I$ are $0$ and $R/I$ which correspond to $R$ and $I$, the only ideals that contain $I$.