# In which of the cases $F = \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $F = Q$ the quotient ring $F[x]/(x^2+3)$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

In which of the cases $F = \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $F = Q$ is the quotient ring $F[x]/(x^2+3)$ a field?

I have no idea where to even begin with this

Comment: $R/I$ is a field precisely when $I$ is a maximal ideal. For polynomials, $(f(x))$ is maximal precisely if $f(x)$ is irreducible. Is $x^2+3$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? What about over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x^2+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the ideal $(x^2+3)$ is maximal, hence $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+3)$ is a field (Used the following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776130/fraleighs-proof-that-m-is-a-maximal-ideal-if-and-only-if-r-m-is-a-field)), whereas, $x^2+3 $ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, as $1$ is a root . So $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3)$ is not a field.

Comment: Note that $x^2+3$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because $x^2+3\equiv x^2+1\equiv x^2+2x+1\equiv (x+1)^2\mod 2$.

Comment: @Mark That is what I have written in my answer that $(x^2+3)$ is reducible, as $1$ is a root.

Comment: I agree, I just thought it might be interesting for OP to see the explicit factorization as well, but didn't think that it was enough to be a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)\in F[x]$, then

> $$F[x]/(p(x))\; \text{is a field} \iff p(x)\; \text{is irreducible in F}.$$

I hope you can carry on from here.