# why $\varphi(J)=(J+I)/I$ and not $J/I$ where $\varphi:R\longrightarrow R/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. I want to show that there is a bijection between the ideal of $R$ containing $I$ and the ideal of $R/I$. Let $\varphi: I\longrightarrow R/I$ defined by $\varphi(x)=x+I$. Let $J$ an ideal of $R$ containing $I$. Why $$\varphi(J)=(J+I)/I$$
and not $\varphi(J)=J/I$ ? Indeed, $$\varphi(J)=\{x+I\mid x\in J\}=J/I.$$

Comment: Yes, compare with the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69578/bijection-between-ideals-of-r-i-and-ideals-containing-i).

Comment: Because $J/I$ means nothing if $I$ is not contained in $J$.

Comment: @egreg: Like I said: $J$ is an ideal containing $I$.

Comment: And, in this case $J+I=J$, so where's the problem? You're probably confusing with the general statement that $\varphi(J)=(J+I)/I$ for *all* ideals of $R$, containing $I$ or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $J$ is an ideal containing $I$, $J+I=J$ anyway, because $I+J$ is the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $J$. So there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably being misled by the general statement that, for *every* ideal $J$ of $R$ (containing $I$ or not),
$$
\varphi(J)=(J+I)/I
$$
In the special case when $I\subseteq J$, obviously $J+I=J$.